# how to convert an Item (dynamodbv2.document.Item) object into JSON in java?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i'm implementing a lambda function in aws. i use dynamodb to store data and the application is written using java. the function is getting item from dynamodb and returns it as response. i want to return its values as JSON for the response. i use the following code but it returns {"empty:false"} in aws lambda test. but when i return it as String it prints the values. but i need it in Json.

Table table = dynamoDb.getTable(DYNAMODB_TABLE_NAME);

Item searchedItem = table.getItem("name", input.getName());

String name = searchedItem.getString("name");

int count = searchedItem.getInt("count");

MapjsonMap=new HashMap<>();
jsonMap.put("name",name);

jsonMap.put("count",count);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(searchedItem.toJSONPretty());

for (String key:jsonMap.keySet()) {

```
json.put(key,jsonMap.get(key));
```

}

return json;

i expect the result to contain the values of dynamodb and it returns {"empty":false}.

Comment: There are about dozen implementation of JSONObject in various libraries. Which library are you using?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj  i use followings in maven

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: format your question properly :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly i got fixed the problem. the aws lambda is auto converting java model objects and json. no need to do it manually by us :-D  just return the result in a corresponding java POJO object and you'll get the Json output in aws. thanks everyone for commenting. cheers.